# PSCustomObject and overload method Where

Tags: string, powershell

I'm poking around a PSCustomObject and the PowerShell ISE auto complete showed me something interesting that I cannot seem to find more information about.

If you've got a variable containing PSCustomObject, there appears to be a not easily found method for filtering.

Would this method for filtering be faster than using the pipeline and `Where-Object`?

```
$CusomObject.Where({$_ -like '*hidden*'})
```

Using `$CustomObject | Get-Member -Force` does not list this overload.  I found [reference to this overload here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx) but cannot seem to find much use of this in my searching.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just appears to execute a script block and confirm the return is True. From limited testing the Where is faster (~1 second ) on a PS Object. Note: [Stopwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668090/powershell-timer-stopwatch-accuracy) may be inaccurate. Where-Object has documentation and executes faster than the ForEach-Object. [BeWhere](http://blog.simonw.se/where-method-in-powershell-4-breaks-my-objects/) There's bugs in PSv4.

Where Script Block

```
write-host "Started at $(get-date)"
$j = $i.Where({$_ -like "*"})
write-host "Ended at $(get-date)"
write-host "Total Elapsed Time: $($elapsed.Elapsed.ToString())"
```

00:00:00.0309266

[ForEach-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849731.aspx)

```
$elapsed = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
write-host "Started at $(get-date)"
$j = $i | %{$_ -like "*"}
write-host "Ended at $(get-date)"
write-host "Total Elapsed Time: $($elapsed.Elapsed.ToString())"
```

00:00:01.0555753

[Where-Object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715.aspx)

```
$elapsed = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
write-host "Started at $(get-date)"
$j = $i | ?{$_ -like "*"}
write-host "Ended at $(get-date)"
write-host "Total Elapsed Time: $($elapsed.Elapsed.ToString())"
```

00:00:00.0348174