# Get output of vagrant process when using Measure-Command

Tags: powershell, vagrant, output, stdout, metrics

I want to collect some metrics when provisioning my Vagrant dev machines and found [Measure-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-command?view=powershell-5.1). But I don't get any output when running Vagrant commands:

```
PS VagrantTest> Measure-Command {vagrant up}

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 14
Milliseconds      : 183
Ticks             : 141838408
TotalDays         : 0,000164164824074074
TotalHours        : 0,00393995577777778
TotalMinutes      : 0,236397346666667
TotalSeconds      : 14,1838408
TotalMilliseconds : 14183,8408
```

When running Vagrant standalone I got more information about the progress like here:

```
PS VagrantTest> vagrant up
Bringing machine 'rancher-base-box' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> rancher-base-box: Checking if box 'ubuntu/xenial64' is up to date...
==> rancher-base-box: A newer version of the box 'ubuntu/xenial64' for provider 'virtualbox' is
==> rancher-base-box: available! You currently have version '20181113.0.0'. The latest is version
==> rancher-base-box: '20181114.0.0'. Run `vagrant box update` to update.
[...]
```

My goal is to see the regular output of vagrant and display the metrics of its execution time after the command has finished. Does this work using `Measure-Command` or is it required to collect execution time on my own using `(Get-Date).Milliseconds` or [StopWatch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14669173/9428314)?

Following the KISS principle, I would like to use existing commands instead of writing my own metrics.

Comment: [Start-/Stop-Transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Host/Start-Transcript?view=powershell-5.0) will include start and end times but only with a resolution of whole seconds. So your StopWatch link may be the better option.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Start-process -RedirectStandardOutput` ?

It will output to file 
[doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6)

Or :

`-NoNewWindow -PassThru` could do the trick